# How to force windows ReadyBoost

Tags: windows, usb, memory, readyboost

I have laptop with 6 GB RAM, and I found out about ReadyBoost, but when I connect the drive and open ReadyBoost tab in properties, it says that my device is fast enough. But I need the extra RAM for some task. Anybody help?

Comment: ReadyBoost is not extra RAM. Neither is swap/the pagefile by the way, but it comes closer, depending on your actual requirements.

Comment: Readyboost is basically a cache for your hard disk, it has nothing to do with RAM and it is not even close to being a substitute.

Comment: "But I need the extra RAM for some task." - Even if you were to enable it, ReadyBoost would provide ZERO performance gains, given your system specifications.  Due to your specifications, Microsoft has made it impossible to enable ReadyBoost, so the only solution to "needing more memory" is to install additional modules.